# Fetching all Mongo documents based on different combinations of values of same query parameters using Spring MongoRepository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am writing a web service in which I need to provide in the response of a user's REST request a list of documents from MongoDb. The filter parameters are provided in the request payload of the request. I need to fetch all documents using Spring's MongoRepository interface which match a combination of parameters. The following query applied directly on the collection works the way I want:

```
db.getCollection('userCollection').find({ '$and' : [ { 'admin':'admin1', 'address':'add1'}, {'$or': [{ 'name' : { '$in':['Amy','Maya'] } }, {'school': 'S1', 'college': 'Col1', 'company': 'CompCop'}, {'school': 'S2', 'college': 'Col1', 'company': 'CompShop'}]} ]})
```

So I need to do the following:

1. All documents must have "admin"="admin1" and "address"="add1"
2. Documents must either have "name" as one of ["Amy", "Maya"] or they must have one of the following of school-college-company combinations-

   `{'school': 'S1', 'college': 'Col1', 'company': 'CompCop'}, {'school': 'S2', 'college': 'Col1', 'company': 'CompShop'}`

These values and the number of such combinations can differ based on what is provided in the web request coming dynamically.

This second point is what I am having trouble incorporating in my JSON based Query in java using the @Query annotation.

I want to provide this information as part of the following repository method:

```
@Query({'$and': [{'admin': ?0, 'address': ?1}, {'$or': [{'name': {'$in': ?2}}, <add solution here for adding list of school-college-company combinations> ]}]})
public List<Users> find(String admin, String address, List<String> names, <insert parameters for 'school-college-company' combinations>);
```

I searched for a solution where I can provide a list of objects of a type which has the parameters as

```
class FilteringClass {
    String school;
    String college;
    String company;
}
```

but without any luck.

I began by trying to collect each "school", "college" and "company" as separate lists and providing these as query parameters but obviously, this is not quite right since it will fetch documents with every possible permutation of the values and not as a unique combination of the three.

Do let me know if there is any solution the way I need it as mentioned above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the querying conditions vary dynamically You should use QueryDsl or use MongoTemplate to query instead of using Repository class

Comment: Sure, that's my fix at the moment. Still wondering if there is a way to have a Repository call instead. They're also extremely convenient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a class exactly as mentioned in the question:

```
class SCCFilter {
String school;
String college;
String company;
}
```

When the request comes from the user with these parameters, for each element in the request payload, I pick the school, college and company values and store them in a list of 'filters'.

(Of course, this can be optimized to avoid duplicates but as a solution to the problem above, it works alright)

Then I wrote the following query:

```
@Query("{ '$and' : [ { 'admin' : ?0 , 'address' : ?1 } , { '$or' : [{'name': {'$in': ?2 }}, {'$or': ?3 }] }]}")
public List<Users> find(String admin, String address List<String> names, List<SCCFilter> filters)
```

And this is the final query I extracted from the logs at run-time to test (successfully) in the Mongo DB:

```
{ "$and" : [ { "admin" : "admin1" , "address" : "addr1"} , { "$or" : [ { "name" : { "$in" : [ "Amy" , "Maya"]}} , { "$or" : [ {'school': 'S1', 'college': 'Col1', 'company': 'CompCop'}, {'school': 'S2', 'college': 'Col1', 'company': 'CompShop'}]}]}]}
```

Much more readable than using MongoTemplate!